# how to print the var value in html body

Tags: javascript, html

I am using following code to print the text in html body i want that i have var which has value hello it should concatenate with the body text to show hi hello.

```
   $("#commandEmail1").click(function() {

presenter.command("emailSend",{
    "toEmail": "jani_06sw@yahoo.com",
    "toName": "Jani",
    "subject": "email test",
    "body": "Single Attachment",
    "bodyHtml":" Hi",
    "attachments": [""]
}, status);
return false;
    });
```

I want that hello should be with Hi like Hi hello so how may i concatenate that var to this function.

here is the js link

http://collabedit.com/49grk

Comment: I'm sorry, but your question does not make much sence.

Comment: @Jonasm how to concatenate a varible in html body without using java script did you get now and there is nothing to downvote the question

Comment: You have to use javascript to concat the html with a variable

Comment: You may have to give more information on what `presenter` is.  It looks like it's an email plugin, so you may be wanting something different than what you're asking

Comment: @presenter is a javascript api for email sending

Comment: Right, but I'm not familiar with it, so you might want to provide a link.  More than likely what you're asking is probably simple, so it may not matter

Comment: @vol7ron i have given the js link you can check please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#commandEmail1").click(function() {

   var extra_text = "hello";                 // your extra text

   presenter.command("emailSend",{
      "toEmail"     : "jani_06sw@yahoo.com",
      "toName"      : "Jani",
      "subject"     : "email test",
      "body"        : "Single Attachment",
      "bodyHtml"    : "Hi " + extra_text,    // concatentate with `+` operator
      "attachments" : [""]
   }, status);

   return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure i fully understand what you are trying to acceive but to concatenate a variable to another in javascript you use the + operater

```
eg. "bodyHtml":" Hi" + helloVar,
```

Answer (score 0):

So lets assume you have an Elemen, you want to concat text to, and one which triggers a function when clicked on it. Then a propertie of an Object should be concatenated to the Element.

Given this HTML

```
  <div id="myDiv">Hello</div>  
  <div id="clickMe">Click Me</div>
```

and following Example

```
var myObject = {
  propToConcat:"Hi" //This is the property you want to be concatenated
};

var clickElement = document.getElementById("clickMe"); //This is your Element, the Click event is added to

var concatElement = document.getElementById("myDiv"); //This is the Element where you display the Text;


clickElement.addEventListener("click",concat); //THis adds the EventListener *You use Jquerys '.click' method for this* 

function concat () {
  concatElement.innerHTML += " " + myObject.propToConcat; //This is what you looking for.
}
```

So the line `concatElement.innerHTML += " " + myObject.propToConcat;`
Accesses the `innerHTML` property of you DOM Element, and appends a space and your Objects propertie.

Then this is how the Output looks before

[image]

And after

[image]

I hope you understand the Example, as i didn't get the Context you are using your code with.

Heres a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/equvuv/1/edit)